Populate Azure custom task picklist's option dynamically
I got an Azure custom task written with Typescript. The task has a picklist defined in its task.json.
I want to be able to populate the options of the pick list based on the value picked on another picklist.
Is there a way to do something like this pseudo code:
const options1 = { option1: value1, option2: value2, option3: value3 }
const options2 = { option1: othervalue1, option2: othervalue2, option3: othervalue3 }

let mainChoice = tl.getInput("firstpicklist", true);
let picklistObj = tl.getObject("secondPickList");
if(mainChoice==="1")
{
   picklistObj.options = options1;
}
else
{
   picklistObj.options = options1;
}

If there's no option to populate a direct object, is it possible somehow to take values from an Azure var group?

Can you share how to define multiple picklist value in tasks.json? Depending on your needs, you need to populate another picklist option after selecting the picklist. How did you define the populated options in tasks.json？

@NoNameLittle I don't know of other ways besides defining the usual way with every option hard coded. I want to have the main pick list with hard coded options and then have a listener that runs every time the user chooses an option in that list and loads the correct object of options to the second pick list

@NoNameLittle So do you have an answer?

@CodeMonkey Did you look at the documentation and the task.json schema? You can define multiple picklists for the various permutations you have in mind, with visibleRules defined on them that ensures only the appropriate picklist is visible.

@DanielMann That's nice for a classic pipeline, but it means whoever is using the task in a yaml pipeline will need to know all the pick lists' names and not all of them are relevant and its a mess with a yaml pipeline

This is not a complete answer, more parts that might help to get you in the right direction then. Also, there is no refresh trigger for the dropdown I think.
Do you know about dataSourceBindings?
This is a bit of a hidden feature. Couldn't find this welldocumented.
It should be part of the task.json file at the same level like id and inputs:
 "dataSourceBindings": [
    {
      "target": "versionSpec",
      "endpointId": "tfs:teamfoundation",
      "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}/_apis/settings/entries/host/my-extensions-json-doc?api-version=7.1-preview",
      "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value['Current'].versions[?(@.state > 0 && @.state < 6)]",
      "resultTemplate": "{ \"Value\" : \"{{{id}}}\", \"DisplayValue\" : \"{{{name}}}\" }"
    }
  ],

You see the target property pointing to versionSpec, which is the picklist's name, like this:
"inputs": [
    {
      "name": "versionSpec",
      "type": "pickList",
      "label": "Some version",
      "defaultValue": "default", <!-- set to the 'default' option in the options jsonstring below
      "options": { "default": "Default (see version with * prefixed)" },
      "properties": {
        "EditableOptions": "False", <-- might be true for you
        "PopulateDefaultValue": "True", <-- not sure what effect this has
        "DisableManageLink": "True" <-- in task editor show some link
      }
    }
  ],

The yaml editor might complain about the dynamic loaded values after picking one of the datasource values from the binding. Not sure how to solve that, guess its not possible.
Creating some second input and second data source binding, you could alternate between input 1 and 2 together with visibility. But that would only be dynamic in the task editor for yaml, or the classic definition.
With using the visibleRule on both inputs, like demonstrated here.
Btw. the endpointId is also used by ADO itself. Using the current context of ADO project etc. Not sure if this is good practice, but for me it works.
I guess it is possible to supply your own API here, but didn't try that myself. One SO question I used to get at this point is this one.

And where are the values themselves which are added as the options of the picklist?

Most of the sources for adding/editing are here as an example how to create some settings page (made visible apart from the task, via its extension). I extracted the version from the marketplace to see how all that was created, as the repo doesn't show it all.
