Populating Azure custom task pick list with a service connection
As I understand, you can use a service connection to load options in a picklist in Azure custom task.
My questions is what kind of data can be loaded and from where exactly? Can I use it to access an Azure resource like a var group of a repo in Azure and get values from there to load to the pick list? Can you show an example of how to do it?

What do you mean about "a var group of a repo in Azure"?

@BrightRan-MSFT This is a var group:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

@BrightRan-MSFT BTW there's a more general question here if maybe you'd know how to answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78266312/populate-azure-custom-task-picklists-option-dynamically

A variable group does not belong to a repository in Azure DevOps, it is set and used for pipelines.

@BrightRan-MSFT The question is also about a pipeline task.. so what is the answer to the question?

You question is about developing a custom extension. If it is an existing extension, you need to get the source code of it and try to rewrite the code based on your demands. Then publish the updated extension. @CodeMonkey

@BrightRan-MSFT Did you looke at the link to the question I posted a few messages earlier? That was about an existing extension and maybe you'd know how to solve that

I posted an answer with some suggestions that may be helpful for you. Check and it. @CodeMonkey

I'm not a expert but i can share my knowledge with you.
In Azure DevOps, using a service connection to populate options in a picklist within a custom task typically involves fetching data from external services or Azure resources. The ServiceConnection acts as a bridge, providing the necessary authentication and authorization to access resources.
What kind of data can be loaded and from where exactly?
You can load any data that the external service's API can return, as long as it can be accessed via the service connection you configure.

List of resources.
Configuration data or metadata from you services.
Data store in external systems that you can access via APIs(branches from GitHub Repos... )

Can I use it to access an Azure resource like a var group of a repo in Azure and get values from there to load to the pick list?
Accessing data from an Azure DevOps Variable Group or repository files directly to populate a picklist in a custom task isn't straightforward because Azure DevOps does not directly support querying these types of Azure DevOps entities for picklist values without custom implementation. However, you can achieve this with a few additional steps involving the Azure DevOps Services REST API.

Set Up the Azure DevOps Service Connection
Modify the task.json File
PowerShell Script to Fetch Data
Handling and Displaying Data

But I could not give you an example how the practical thing works.

Is it possible to populate the options of a picklist dynamically with a constant object? Something like: tl.get(myPickList).SetOptions(optionsObject);   ?

Or maybe you have an example using a service connection to populate the options of a pick list with hard coded values but based on some logic which tells me which values to retrieve?

In Azure DevOps extensions, particularly when developing custom tasks for Azure Pipelines, the method you described (tl.get(myPickList).SetOptions(optionsObject)) is not standard. Azure DevOps custom tasks typically use predefined schemas and configurations to handle inputs and their interactions. However, if you are implementing or manipulating UI elements within a custom page or using JavaScript in some custom extensions, similar functionality might be achievable in a web environment context.

Do you have such examples? That's the main idea of the question

Sadly I don't, Ive just theoretically ideas about it from azure certificates & learning pathes. - maybe ask KI or Microsoft docs for examples, sometimes u got good notes

If you have the source code of the extension, you can try to rewrite it:

You can try to call the Variablegroups related REST API in the JavaScript/TypeScript script file of the extension to get the data of variable groups. See "Call a REST API".

In the JavaScript/TypeScript script file, you can parse the JSON type response of the API call to get the data you require. If the data you require is a list/array, you can try to use an array variable to store the fetched data.

On the UI of the extension, you can add a combo control (see "Use the combo control"). Then you can pass the array variable to the combo control to fill in its drop-down list.




I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing? I was talking here about an Azure pipeline custom task. You define its inputs using the task.json file and code in the index.ts file.. What you linked with the combo control is not it (or at least not in a way I'm using)

@CodeMonkey, the values of drop-down list on a pipeline task normally are get from backend API call set in the JavaScript/TypeScript script file of the extension, just like I mentioned above. Users cannot manually (or other ways) fill in the custom values.

@CodeMonkey, Again, you need to rewrite the source code of the extension to let it can get and fill in the data you want into the drop-down list.

But what you said is not true for a custom task. You define a pick list with its values hardcoded like this:
"inputs": [
{
"name": "mylist",
"type": "pickList",
"label": "myLabel",
"defaultValue": "val1",
"required": true,
"options": {
"val1": "val1",
"val2": "val2",
},
"helpMarkDown": "Select a val."
}, ... (and so on for the rest of the inputs)

@CodeMonkey, No, it's not hard-code, it normally will auto get the data by calling the specified API based on the inputs you provide in other fields (for example, organization name, project name, an existing service connection with authorization information, etc..) on the task.

Ok so that's basically what the question is about - mainly about part 3 in your answer. I just don't see there usage of task.json for defining the inputs for the UI/YAML pipeline. I was expecting to use tl from the import * as tl from "azure-pipelines-task-lib/task" to somehow get the picklist and define its values

And if you could take a look at this question which is more specific, you'd understand better what I use and it could help a lot:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78266312/populate-azure-custom-task-picklists-option-dynamically

Did you have a chance to look at that other question?
